# Streaming data ingestion to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We have an application that will deliver streaming data and the application vendor asks for a web endpoint to access BigQuery for loading of streaming data. What is the preferred pattern when loading streaming data? 
If I would like to use pubsub->Dataflow->BQ, how do I set up a web endpoint to publish to a topic?
Any suggestions are appreciated - I have never done this :D

Br
Cris

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want, but there is a [template](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/provided-templates#cloudpubsubtobigquery) (which you can use right away or edit it to fit your use case) for Pub/Sub to BQ. Also, here you can find how to publish by using [Pub/Sub Client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library). Was this what you wanted?

Comment: Is it possible to do an "auto detect" of schema with the template? I dont find such an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data will be stored only in BigQuery and there is no foreseen any pre-processing go directly with the [BigQuery Streaming API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery). It's really performant 100.000 req/sec.

Use DataFlow -> BQ when you want to deal with collections, transformations multiple destination sinks.

In the beginning just go with BQ APi, then as things evolve, you can anytime change to a Dataflow -> BQ approach.

Comment: Ok thanks. It was decided that we are going for Pub/sub. Now I need to create the table in BQ to receive the data from pub/sub but this table needs to have the same schema as the json sent. Is there a way of auto detecting the schema?